# Chrome extension script sometimes loads before webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add content on to a webpage with my chrome extension but it needs the page to fully load so that it can parse out class names and ids of specific attributes in the HTML documents of these webpages. Sometimes it works but other times, whenever I use document.getElementsByClassName() in my scripts it returns null instead of [object HTMLDivElement]. I tried adding   `"run_at": "document_end"` to the content_scripts key of my manifest.json as well as using the code below at the top of my script, but script keeps running before all div elements load on the webpage. What can I do to fix this issue? All I need is for my script to run after all HTML elements are fully loaded on the page. I can add more code if needed but I need to keep the specifics of my project private so I can't add much more than what I am already posting.

content.js:

```
if (document.readyState === 'loading') {  // Loading hasn't finished yet
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startExtension);
} else {  // `DOMContentLoaded` has already fired
  startExtension(); //Runs the rest of the script
}
function startExtension() {
  alert(document.getElementsByClassName("class_name"));
}
```

Comment: Your snippet is confusing, Could you not just have the DOMContentLoaded and remove the outer condition? Also think about what you are trying to do, if the readystate is loading, wait for the content to load with DOMContentLoaded, otherwise, just start the extension but do not wait to check if the DOMContentLoaded? Also there is more than 'loading' as a ready state, so anything other than loading will run your startExtention() at the moment.

Comment: Let me try to make this simpler, I want the startExtension() function to run after all attributes of the HTML document have completely loaded. If they haven't all loaded before my script runs, then calling document.getElementsByClassName() on one of the objects I'm looking for returns null. This doesn't happen every time but does tend to happen most of the time, so I need to find some way to start my function after all div tags and thier children load.

Comment: I gave you the answer to your problem in my comment above.

Comment: Yeah it's not calling the startExtension() function after the page loaded

Comment: Yeah give that a try. I had a read on readyState and can see the logic behind what you were trying to do now too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this problem. I used this code below and so far it's working each time I reload the webpage:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      startExtension();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Content scripts run by default after readyState is complete so usually you don't need to change anything, and the original code you've posted in the question is also not needed (assuming you didn't use "run_at":"document_start"). A real solution is either listening to `load` event on `window` or a simple setTimeout/setInterval or MutationObserver. More info: [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Well before I included the code from my answer, it was running the scripts before the webpage completely loaded, so this was the solution I needed and it works.

Comment: It works just because this creates an additional almost zero delay, which is mentioned in my comment.